# How to enable left to right transition effect on a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am creating a navbar using Bootstrap 4 where initially the logo (on left side) is hidden.

Only the navbar menu items will be displayed and on scroll, the logo will appear. So when the logo appears, I'm trying to enable a smooth slide animation effect of the menu items (left to right). Now since there's no transition, it simply goes to the right without any animation effect.

I'm unable to decide where to put the transition CSS on. :( Please help.

*Code below (for simplicity I'm using a button instead of scroll effect)
Also, view in 'full page' mode, else the small viewport will show the mobile version of the menu.*

```js
(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#my-btn').click(function() {
      $('#my-navbar-logo').toggleClass('d-sm-none');
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="wrapper-navbar" class="sticky-top">

    <a class="skip-link sr-only sr-only-focusable" href="#content">Skip to content</a>

    <div class="container">

      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">

        <!-- my logo-->
        <span id="my-navbar-logo" class="d-block d-sm-none"><a href="#" class="navbar-brand custom-logo-link"
                        rel="home"><img src="#" class="img-fluid" alt="my logo" width="170" height="35"></a></span>


        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                Dropdown
                            </a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
            <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
          </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- .container -->
    </nav>


  </div>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <div class="mt-5 mx-5">
    <button id="my-btn" class="btn btn-primary">Click me</button>
  </div>
```

Comment: How d-sm-none class looks like? can you post you css also?

Comment: .d-sm-none {
    display: none !important;
}

Comment: You can put for example transition: all 1s ease with transform: translateX(100px) in d-sm-none class

Comment: Doesn't work. Tried just now.

Comment: You can try here, if you want: https://codepen.io/littlelebowski112/pen/pojBmYV

Comment: You can't transition the `display` property.

Comment: I can't see css code, can you please post css also?

Comment: @Paulie_D Then what should be an elegant hack in this case? Ahed, CSS added

Comment: My approach is to have it out via translateX(-100px) then move it back to translateX(100px) on scroll, just random numbers.

Comment: @AhedKabalan Can you edit the codepen and show how? I don't understand.

Comment: @AhedKabalan your were 100% correct and gave me a solution that is relevant to my problem. My question for closed but my problem is not related to transition of display property. I used translateX to move the menu left to right with smooth animation. Much thanks.